# Only the last element of the linked list is displayed

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been trying to create a linked list in c++. But only the last element of the linked list is displayed. I have searched for the error but i cannot find it. I have implemented the logic that I learned form c language. All the nodes are connecting properly. But still i cannot find the error.
This logic works on c language.
Please help.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class node{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
}*head,*newnode,*temp;

node* getnode();
node* create(int);
void display(node*);

int main()
{
    int n;
    head=getnode();
    cout<<"Enter the no of nodes: ";
    cin>>n;
    head=create(n);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}

node *getnode()
{
    head=new node();
    head->next=nullptr;
    return(head);
}

node *create(int n)
{
    head=getnode();
    cout<<"Enter the value of node 1: ";
    cin>>head->data;
    temp=getnode();
    temp=head;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        newnode=getnode();
        cout<<"Enter the value of node "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>newnode->data;
        newnode->next=nullptr;
        temp->next=newnode;
        temp=newnode;
    }
    return(head);
}

void display(node *head)
{
    while(head!=nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"->"<<head->data;
        head=head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because `getnode` just overwrites head every time it's called?

Comment: This doesn't look right: `temp=getnode(); temp=head;` You might want to walk through your logic again.

Comment: For information, when you implement a linked list, the node implementation should not be accessible from outside your linked list class (which is missing here by the way).

Comment: It does not work in C either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class node{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node(int x)
    {
        data=x;
        next=nullptr;
    }
}*head,*newnode,*temp;

node* create(int);
void display(node*);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the no of nodes: ";
    cin>>n;
    head=create(n);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}

node *create(int n)
{
        
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int x;
        cout<<"Enter the value of node "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>x;
        newnode=new node(x);
        if(i==0)
        {
            head=temp=newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next=newnode;
            temp=newnode;
        }
        
    }
    return(head);
}

void display(node *head)
{
    while(head!=nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"->"<<head->data;
        head=head->next;
    }
}
```

Ive just created a constructor for creating a new node and used a temp pointer for keeping track of the last inserted element in the list. Do keep in mind it is always best to have your head pointer fixed and use another pointer for traversals. The problem with your code was that your head pointer points to the last inserted element always.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use local variables

`*head,*newnode,*temp` are globals. Everytime you call a function, you're overwriting them. Make them local variables.

#### Memory leaks

You also leak memory in main() with:

```
head=getnode();
```

And in create() with:

```
temp=getnode();
```

#### Put it all together

https://repl.it/repls/MedicalEquatorialFlashmemory#main.cpp